# Hide The Textview For Login Logout Functionality in android

Tags: android, textview, show-hide

i am trying to hide the textview runtime just because of  when user is login user can't see the SIGN UP and LOGIN DETAILS like USERNAME AND PASSWORD EDIT BOX and GO BUTTON
and if user is not login user can see all the details

you can see in the image first is  login image and  second is logout image

When user is Login

[image]

when user is logout
[image]

Comment: You can do that on runtime by setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) or setVisibility(View.GONE). But what exactly your question is?

Comment: you can see now the image is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shared preferences for that, first time store user name and password value into shared preferences and next time if shared preferences value is not null then set visibility is gone or invisible of textview and button using below code.

```
mTxtViewUserName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mTxtViewPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mBtnLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

For Set Visible use below code.

```
mTxtViewUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mTxtViewPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mBtnLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

For Store Value into shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("isLogin", "True");
prefsEditor.commit();
```

For Get Value from Shared Preferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String isLogin = myPrefs.getString("isLogin");
```

Comment: yes you right is hide the textview but if textview is hidden than is still use the blank space on textview area i want to remove the textview space when is invisible than use this space for MYPROFILE AND LOGOUT textview how to do this

Comment: @AndroidNew You can dynamically Create Design of XMl Layouts and another option is create one splash activity and check shared preferences value in splash activity and then select login activity if user is not logged in and if user is logged in then open another activity.

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer No need to dynamically create but just simply take the VIEW.Gone is not take any space and View.INVISIBLE take space so i am use the VIEW.Gone and is working fine thaks for your answer also thanks for SHARED PREFERENCES answer

Answer (score 2):

`textView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` - hide text

`textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` - show text